# Неправильно работает mousewheel (swfwheel) во flash в chrome

Tags: google-chrome, javascript, actionscript

Это код на actionscript mousewheel_as3.swf

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import SWFWheel;
SWFWheel.initialize(stage);
SWFWheel.browserScroll = false;
function handleMouseWheel(event:MouseEvent):void {
    if ((event.delta > 0 && box_mc.y > 0) || (event.delta < 0 && box_mc.y < 270)) {box_mc.y = box_mc.y - (event.delta * 1); 
    }
    }
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_WHEEL, handleMouseWheel);
```

Пример тут - ilempi.ru/konstruktor. Квадратик двигается только если навести на него (в хроме), в IE двигается как нужно. swfwheel отсюда - http://www.libspark.org/svn/as3/SWFWheel/. Как вообще сделать так чтобы если мышь во флеше то прокрутка только там (во всех браузерах).

Comment: По моему если фокус стоит на флешке, то все браузеры ведут себя одинаково, крутится внутри флешки. Просто разные браузеры по разному ставят по умолчанию фокус на флешку, нужно этим озаботиться. У меня (хром) даже после наведения на квадратик не скролится колесом, только после клика не нем.

Comment: Вот именно все по-разному ведут себя, а еще разные версии... Пробовал еще github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel тоже хром глючит